# HTML doesn't recognize my CSS after I inserted a new element with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this project, where I want to build an admin panel for a site. I use a popup-box that pops up when you click on a special setting.

I want to fill the HTML content with JavaScript code into this popup-box, so that I am able to only use one for all the settings

The problem is, that the html code that I insert in the popup-box before I make it visible does not apply the style from the classes that I want.

Code of how it's opened:

```
function open_popup_box(heading, content){
  $("#popup_box_heading").html(heading);
  $("#popup_box_content").html(content);
  $("#popup_box").fadeIn();
  $("#popup_box_bg").addClass("show");
}
```

The class that I want to insert an element from is defined in the style.css.
The only thing that works is inline style, but that's not an option as I want to use hover and other CSS things

Does somebody know how to fix this?

As requested the CSS:

```
.custom_select{
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-position: right 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: .5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!-- Just to let you know in which order I loaded the files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external/css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="external/js/globalfunctions.js"></script>



<div id="popup_box">
    <table id="popup_box_table">
      <tr id="popup_box_header">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td width="50px">
                <i id="popup_box_close_icon" class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </td>
              <td id="popup_box_heading">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td id="popup_box_content">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This is the part of the JS that opens the popup-box (with inline style set right now because its the only thing I get to work):

```
var content='<div id="popup_box_content_div"><select class="custom_select" id="lang_select" style="border-radius: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; background-position: right 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: .5em; padding-right: 1.5em; width: 40%; font-size: 16px;">';
$.each(language_list, function(i, lang){
   content+='<option>';
   content+=lang.showName;
   content+='</option>';
});
content+='</select></div>';
open_popup_box("Choose your preferred Language", content);
```

Comment: For dynamic content, few JS events will not work but CSS will work as expected. Check whether CSS file is inserted properly. Or share the code in jsfiddle to correct it.

Comment: Show the html and the css. My hunch is that it's a selector issue, where you don't have the classes you want to use inside the html strings .

Comment: @Shilly I added some more code

Comment: @VenkateshK Doesnt really work for me. Don't know why either

Comment: Is the JS you show inside the globalfunctions.js file? If so, does that file defer running until document ready? Just asking since I can't reproduce the issue on IE11 or Chrome 57. Any change made to the custom_select css is shown inside the browsers I tried. So the issue is probably not with the code shown. Any way you could post the exact minimal code that has the issue?

Comment: @Shilly Thank you very much for your help. The problem was not the code itself, but a problem with Chrome. It had cached my old style.css and didnt reload it after like a hundred refreshes... so the class didnt even exist in my browser even though it did in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of inline style in the 'content' variable in JS.
The only reason why CSS might not work is if the CSS selector is actually a child of some other selector and what you're appending isn't a child of that selector. 
If you are using SCSS, is that CSS selector nested in some other selector? If you are using vanilla CSS, is that the entire selector or does it have some other elements in front (eg .foo .custom_select {})?

Comment: That inline is there, because I cant get it to work without it. if I remove it, it doesnt recognize the styles anymore. And yes I use SCSS, but its nested in nothing - the line i copyed is a standalone and the only thing that affects the .custom_select .

Comment: @MauriceNino In that case, did you actually run SCSS build process, after adding the relevant CSS, so that CSS is built from SCSS?

Comment: yes i did. using the --watch command. actually checked it a hundred times in the style.css, but its definitely there.

Comment: That's very weird as the selectors and everything should work. Try adding display: none !important; to .custom_select. Using that you'll actually be able to see if the issue is with selector (shouldn't be) or with styles for example being overriden somewhere else (which would be my hunch).

Comment: Ok I tried that and nothing changed at first...then i tried the network inspector in chrome and saw that it always loads an old version of my file...

Comment: Thanks for the help...its a problem of chrome and not of the code...and i am sitting here searching 2h for the issue :)

Comment: Then it's a problem with caching. The proper way to solve that would be to add fingerprinting to your build process. To test out if it's a problem with caching, CTRL + shift + R in chrome ;)

Comment: what is fingerprinting if I may ask?
Yeah or just use Firefox from now on haha...

Comment: Every browser will cache assets by default, whether it be FF, Chrome, IE, Safari, etc. As long as the path to a file stays the same, the browser will check if it has that file in cache. You might choose to disable caching, but average user will have it turned on so if your project is going to be live, fingerprinting is a must.Fingerprinting is a process of adding a query to your assets - usually either sequential or based on last modified timestamp. Your path for css won't be styles.css anymore, but it will be styles.css?v=1, next time you change it will be ?v=2 etc. That solves caching issues

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there could be an CSS inheritance issue in your code.  You could use BEM style where you directly style your HTML elements to a specific class with only one level thereby circumventing the cascading of styles.

Alternatively, instead of placing the modal HTML in JS you can add it directly to the page's HTML and just show/hide the modal.  If it still doesn't work then you'd know why as you'll see the conflicts in the browser developer tools.